# Read Dynamics NAV 2009 Table Metadata with SQL

Tags: sql, blob, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

I would like to be able to read the Dynamics NAV 2009 R2 Table Metadata directly from the SQL Server database without requiring the NAV Development Environment. This question is similar to [Read Dynamics NAV Table Metadata with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223762/read-dynamics-nav-table-metadata-with-sql) but I need to access NAV 2009 R2 metadata and that answer doesn't work for me.

I found out that NAV 2009 uses some kind of compression algorithm on blob fields. I need to know what this algorithm is. Or may be any advises how to try to reverse engineer it. Turning compression off is not acceptable.

Comment: This should work. As the answer says there is no custom compression on blob fields. You just have to remove first 4 bytes from blob and then unpack it.

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't work. It seems that in 2009 version compression algorithm is different.