# SOLR - TikaEntityProcessor - BLOB Import

Tags: solr, blob, dynamics-nav

I'm having issues figuring out exactly how to import blob data from a SQL Server database into SOLR. 
This is hooked into NAV as well. I've managed to get the data out of the table within NAV, however I need this data in SOLR for search purposes.

Here's my current dataConfig file.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="dastream" type="FieldStreamDataSource" />
    <dataSource name="db" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=TestingDB" user="sa" password="*******" />
    <document name="items">
        <entity name="item"  query="select [No_], [Desc_ English] as desceng from [Foo$Item]" dataSource="db">
            <field column="No_" name="id" />

            <entity processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="desceng" dataField="item.desceng" name="blob" dataSource="dastream" format="text" >
                <field column="text" name="desceng"  />
            </entity>
        </entity>

    </document>

</dataConfig>
```

The error I keep getting is:

---

Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported type : class java.lang.String

---

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is because Nav stores blobs in his own way. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223762/read-dynamics-nav-table-metadata-with-sql). There ia an example how to extract data using python.

Comment: I've attempted to use the theories in question to create a transformer for the entity I want to deflate. Java seems to have issues when it comes to the deflation on that aspect.

Comment: Well. All options are there. If this doesn't work then you can write a function in Nav to export required blob to file and get file name through web service after this.

Comment: Appreciate the help. After much muddling, I managed to get the Transformer to work. Thanks!