# Reading image directly from the [Tenant Media] table in Microsoft Dynamic Business Central?

Tags: image, microsoft-dynamics

In Microsoft Dynamics Business Central, the images can be saved in the `[Tenant Media]` table. The field `[Mime Type]` tells the type, and the field `Content` stores the binary content (as `varbinary` type).

I need to mirror the images of the goods to another database using the C# code. However, it seems that the `Content` field does not store only the plain binary of the image.

Is the content encrypted somehow? When read to `byte[]`, is it possible to get the image data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a c# solution for NAV 2013 and above based on this solution https://devch.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/accessing-compressed-blobs-from-outside-nav-nav2013-revisited/

```
 byte[] dest = new byte[tenantMedia.Content.Length - 4];
 Array.Copy(tenantMedia.Content, 4, dest, 0, dest.Length);

 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dest);
 using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
 {
      MemoryStream ResultStream = new MemoryStream();
      deflateStream.CopyTo(ResultStream);
      byte[] uncompressedContent = ResultStream.ToArray();

      string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(uncompressedContent);
      Console.WriteLine(base64Image);
  }
```

For version previous to NAV 2013:

http://midynav.blogspot.com/2009/04/blob-fields-with-nav-sql_28.html

> [ Out of the box, NAV flags a "BLOB" field with the property "Compressed" = TRUE. If this is enabled, NAV uses a compression algorithm to save the data more compact. Have in mind that SQL Server does not recognize this "compression", so if you're using BLOB to transfer binary data from NAV to other SQL systems – which could be very smart, but that's a different story! – you should make sure to set "Compressed" to FALSE. But anyway … ]

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/properties/devenv-compressed-property

Comment: Here is a similar solution in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223762/read-dynamics-nav-table-metadata-with-sql